# Many Tag which store database with comma separator css design

Tags: php, css, laravel

I am working a project with laravel now, here I put many tag in a database column with comma separator, like

```
java,laravel,Jquery
```

I need to design these tag like stackoverflow tags system

How can I do this, any help....

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, really.

Make the CSS that will style the tag (psuedo code);:

```
span.tag {
    display:inline-block;
    background:blue;
    color:#fff;
    margin:0 15px;
}
```

Then just implode on the array and glue the span with the class. like this:

```
echo '<span class="tag">'.implode('</span><span class="tag">', $tags).'</span>';
```

Comment: oww, its good, but it make the whole string in a single color, I need to show these tag separately... @Ohgodwhy

Comment: How do I know what colors they should be? I'm sure you can figure this out from what I've given you.